# Extracting llvm::CallInst returned %tmp name

Tags: return, llvm

I have an llvm::CallInst *i, representing this call (taken from *.ll file):

%tmp3 = call i64 @__fdget(i32 %tmp) #5

How do I extract the returned value name (%tmp3 here)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[llvm::Value::getName](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#ad452febc1ac0b394876e640ec03ffa38) contains instruction name.

```
llvm::StringRef name = i->getName();
```